# wso2esb 5.0 - send message from WSO2 to client via WebSocket

Tags: websocket, wso2, wso2-esb

I noticed that WSO2 5.0 released new functionality - websockets. I have familiarized a little bit with these tutorials:

[WebSocket Support](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/WebSocket+Support)

I see that it is possible to send messages from client to WSO2/Backend via WebSockets, but I did not understand if revers communication is available - from WSO2 to client via WebSockets.

I would like to read the message from RabbitMQ in WSO2 ESB and send that message to the JavaScript client connected to the WSO2 via WebSocket.

I will appreciate any code examples.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assuming your jvascript as a web socket endpoint, you can merely use web socket sender [1] to send the message there.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Message+from+a+HTTP+Client+to+a+WebSocket+Endpoint